# How to understand the CHAR_LITERAL rule in java antlr4 lexer file

Tags: java, compiler-construction, antlr4, lexer

[java antlr4 lexer file](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/java/JavaLexer.g4)

```
CHAR_LITERAL:       '\'' (~['\\\r\n] | EscapeSequence) '\'';

fragment EscapeSequence
    : '\\' 'u005c'? [btnfr"'\\]
    | '\\' 'u005c'? ([0-3]? [0-7])? [0-7]
    | '\\' 'u'+ HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit
    ;
```

Why '\r', '\n', ''', '' is excluded in first part，and '\b', '\t', '\f', '"' not excluded in first part?

If I change the rule to this, is it equivalent to the previous rule

```
CHAR_LITERAL:       '\'' (~['\\\r\n\b\f\t\"] | EscapeSequence) '\'';
```

Or change it to this

```
CHAR_LITERAL:       '\'' (~['\\] | EscapeSequence) '\'';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not trying to exclude something like:

```java
char x = `\r`;
```

It's trying to exclude:

```java
char x = '
';
```

That last one is illegal java. A `'` (opening a char literal) can be followed by either an EscapeSequence, or a character, but by exception, not a newline character. (as in, literally pressing enter in your editor, not `\n` which isn't a newline, it's an escape sequence that represents a new line).

In other words, after the single quote, any character is fine, EXCEPT backslash which needs to be excluded, as `EscapeSequence` handles this, and EXCEPT the literal unicode values `0D`/`0A` (CR and LF, in antlrspeak, `\r` and `\n`).

It gets a little confusing perhaps - just make sure you very very carefully count the backslashes:

```
['\\\r\n]
```

That is excluding 4 unicode values, and only 4:

- a single quote. `char x = '';` is not legal java.
- a backslash. Because the ANTLR grammar needs to hop on over to the `EscapeSequence` part to parse that. `char x = '\';` is not legal.
- a newline, either one (CR or LF) - because you can't actually start a new line in the middle of your char literal.

In contrast, the escape sequences aren't looking for `\n`, they are looking for a backslash symbol and then the actual letter 'n'.

Comment: The answer is great and fully answers my confusion. I spent a whole morning consulting chat-gpt, but all the answers given were wrong.